# Google Sheets - summing numbers across a spreadsheet depending on the Column header

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to automate our timesheet process. Each staff member has their own separate Google Sheet which has the dates down one column, and then a varying number of columns named after different projects they are working on.

I want to create an automatic summary of the total number of hours by project by staff member in another Google sheet. Like this:

[image]

I know I can use importRange to pull in numbers from specific cells across a number of different workbooks. But I am struggling to find a way to sum the hours by project without making every staff member have all 60+ projects on their timesheet and keep these in the same order so the cell references never change and break the formulas.

I want a formula which sums numbers in a column IF the header of that column is a specific name e.g. = Project 1.

So the range of the formula would cover a whole spreadsheet, but would only sum 1 column based on the header.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding the problem here but is someting like `=IF(B3="Project 1",SUM(B4:B17),)` ok or not what you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

Just have the hours summed up in each member's sheet and import the sums which you can again sum up for the grand totals.

Please have a look at [this sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13WTqsbi4O49tEQLOMIUxfIJGAttYTUh4wfJ8hkAOOMg/edit?usp=sharing) I prepared for you.