# Count occurrences across sheets, based on criteria

Tags: google-sheets

Is there an elegant—more programatic way—to count across sheets based on some criteria like whether they have been checked.

For example, given the attached sheets, the result would be:

```
Apples:     1
Oranges:    2
Watermelon: 1
```

The best formula I could come up with is :

```
=COUNTIFS(
  {
    '2020'!A:A;
    '2019'!A:A;
    '2018'!A:A
  }
  ,A1,
  {
    '2020'!B:B;
    '2019'!B:B;
    '2018'!B:B
  }
,"✓"
)
```

[image: 2020]

[image: 2019]

[image: 2018]

Comment: What do you mean by "more programatic way"?  Are you looking for built-in functions? Are you open to use a custom function / Google Apps Script?

Comment: Related [Average across sheets Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111836/88163), [Google Sheets - summing numbers across a spreadsheet depending on the Column header](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/132745/88163), [Conversion from Excel to Google Spreadsheet - sum across sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/63023/88163)

Comment: In a way that doesn't require updating the formula with each successive year. Definitely open to GAS.

Comment: Regarding the use of Google Apps Script, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets